# API Rate Limit: Any Idea how to find out the rate Limit of the mojang API?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, request, rate-limiting

Im trying to grab some data from the mojang API. On the wiki website it says the API has a Rate limit of 600 per 10min so that should be 60 requests per minute.
The problem is,I have tried to send a request every 1.2 seconds to not exceed the given Rate-Limit but after just 59 requests it outputs statuscode 429, so sent to many requests... but from the informations i have this cant be the case so my question is, is there a way to check the rate-limit the API has? If yes how do I find it?

Thx for helping

Comment: continuously hit the API until you get status code **error**. then you know rate limit for sure. example: loop for 10000 times w/o break and print i within loop. if you get rate limit then at that point it is understood that value of i will be your actual rate limit for the API.

Comment: but that doesent quite give me the limit, I mean it gives me the calls I can make but not the time I can make them in like mentioned above with 600 per 10min. But I have another question. How does this system work? If I can call the API 60 times in 1 Minute and I call it 59 times in 60 seconds to not exceed the limit, does the limit completely reset after these 60 seconds, so like at 61 seconds I have 59 calls for 60 seconds again?

Comment: yep, i believe that’s how it works

Comment: Do you know if there is any other way to get the rate limit directly from the API?

Answer (score 0):

The general limit is [600 requests per 10 minutes](https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API#:%7E:text=at%20600%20requests%20per%2010%20minutes).
Some endpoints have additional limits (Profile has a limit of around 200 requests per minute according to [this source](https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API#:%7E:text=This%20rate%20limit%20is%20around%20200%20requests%20per%20minute))

Comment: Does requesting the availability of a name from the API refer to the Profile section? I checked the link an that was my source of information too but where did you find that profile has a limit of 200 requests per Minute?